# OpenCV android native camera motion blur

Tags: android, opencv, camera

I'm using the OpenCV Android native camera libraries for image capture in NDK, but while the image acquisition is happening the phone is (necessarily) moving so the images are quite blurry. What options are there to reduce this blur? I don't actually care too much about color fidelity so can sacrifice quality in that area. There doesn't appear to be direct exposure control, but I did find that doing

```
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, -4)
```

seemed to help a bit although -4 is the furthest it would go. I'm not terribly familiar with camera terminology in general so am not sure what effect the other properties might have for me.

Also, I noticed that in the default camera application (Galaxy SIII), the camera motion blur occurs during image preview, which makes sense since OpenCV also grabs preview images. But in video preview (non-recording) mode the image is a lot crisper. Is anyone aware of how I can access this stream?

Comment: Isn't the "crispy" effect you get from the preview just due to performance ? Like when you write you use resources so you get some lag, fps drops and you get blur from motion ? Just a hunch...